# Add new elements in the "basket" in django oscar

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

I'm looking for a way to save products in the cart, but I didn't find much on google and there are no clear examples in the official documentation (https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/2.0.4/ref/apps/basket.html).

So does anyone know which libraries to import and how to save a product programmatically?

I'm waiting for answers, thank you!

Comment: What exactly don't you understand? If you have a `basket` instance (model `Basket`) and a `product` instance (model `Product`) then `basket.add(product)` adds the product to the basket.

Comment: @dirkgroten No strategy class has been assigned to this basket

Comment: This is explained [here](https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/2.0.4/topics/prices_and_availability.html#the-strategy-class), the strategy class is required to determine a price when adding a product to the basket.

Comment: @dirkgroten So I have to write this? strategy = Selector().stategy() and bakset = Basket() basket.strategy = strategy basket.add(product)

Comment: As far as i can see, you shouldn't have to do anything (not even write any view) to use the standard Oscar basket/views etc: Just add the [oscar urls](http://docs.oscarcommerce.com/en/latest/internals/getting_started.html#urls) to your urls.py and you'll have everything there. Look at the sample project.

Comment: @dirkgroten I already did, the problem is that I have a personal editor and then from that editor the system has to add the custom product in the cart

Comment: Have you added the `BasketMiddleware` in your settings? It's the one that adds the strategy to the basket. [Here](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/releases/2.0/src/oscar/apps/basket/views.py#L277)'s the code where oscar itself adds a product to the basket. Use `self.request.basket` to make sure the strategy was added.

Comment: @dirkgroten I tried, however I found the problem, you have to assign to basket.owner the request.user. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same question, and this is what I did in the Django shell:

```
>>> from oscar.apps import catalogue, basket, partner
>>> my_product = catalogue.models.Product.objects.order_by('?').first() #get a random product
>>> my_basket = basket.models.Basket()
>>> my_basket.strategy = partner.strategy.Default()
>>> my_basket.add_product(my_product)
(<Line: Cart #7, Product #3, quantity 1>, True)
>>>
```

Django 3.2, Oscar 3.1, Python 3.9